# Eclipse cannot download org.eclipse.osgi

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, git, maven

When I do `mvn -U clean install` on my maven project, it hangs at

`Downloading: http://repo.softaddicts.ca:8080/archiva/repository/internal/org/eclipse/osgi/org.eclipse.osgi/3.7.0.v20110124-0830/org.eclipse.osgi-3.7.0.v20110124-0830.pom`

I get the corresponding error in eclipse `Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.osgi:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.7.0.v20110124-0830`

I don't get this error for any of my other maven projects. I have compared their poms and the dependencies in which they differ have all installed fine (checked .m2). I have a feeling that it is the port `8080` of http://repo.softaddicts.ca that is causing the problem. Without that port I just get an HTTP error instead of a timeout.

Thanks for the help!

P.S.: I am using SpringToolSuits 3.8.2 RELEASE